# Post-Filename Path Recovery using PHP

Tags: php, url, get

I am trying to recover the path that is provided to me in a GET request. For example, a GET request will be sent to http://myserver.com/index.php/info/PathThatIWantToExtract and I want to pull that information that comes after /info/. This is NOT sent in a typical GET var using index.php?test=hello but instead uses a path after the file name (index.php).

```
 PHP only please.
```

Thanks

Comment: Typically, this'd be handled by your framework's router.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

I was able to get everything working by using $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] along with a few other tricks. Here is the code that got everything working:

```
$fullUrl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $pathThatIWantToExtract = str_replace("http://myserver.com/index.php/info/", "", $fullUrl);
```

Now the info I wanted is stored as a string in $pathThatIWantToExtract